# need help to choose Xpath h1 but not the span inside h1

Tags: xpath, domxpath

I have h1 tag for product title that contains a span tag for some number.
I want an xpath code to extract h1 (product title) but not span

I use the below method and some other method but it didn't work.

```
<h1 class="title">this is product title <span class="number">34</span> </h1>
```

I tried:

```
//h1[contains(concat (" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " title ")]//span[not(contains(@class, " number "))]
```

this xpath gives me only the number : 34

I want to xpath gives me "this is product title"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you should be able to select the first non-blank text node in the `h1` to get the value you want:

```
//h1[contains(concat (" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " title ")]/text()[normalize-space()]
```